# How to edit the template, mobile version of blogger?

Tags: blogger

when I edit the my html template blogger, I can find elements from desktop site.. but looks like I cannot find elements or texts used by the mobile version.

I search text that appears on mobile version and I cannot find it inside the template.

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 2):

To edit your blogger template read [how blogger widgets work](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969).

You can find mobile elements for index pages inside

`<b:includable id='mobile-index-post' var='post'>`

And mobile elements for post pages inside

`<b:includable id='mobile-post' var='post'>`